# How to load mobx state from json?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mobx, mobx-react

I want to store my mobx state in browser localStorage, so, if i use this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/40326316
I save store with toJS, but don't know how to apply it. With extendObservable I get following error `Error: [mobx] 'extendObservable' can only be used to introduce new properties. Use 'set' or 'decorate' instead`
Thanks in advance.

My approach is:

```js
class MyStore {
...
  public async load() {
      const cached = await browser.storage.local.get("cache");
        const data = JSON.parse(cached["cached"]);
        Object.keys(data).forEach(x => {
          (this as any)[x] = (data as any)[x];
       });
...
}
```

But i think this is anitpattern.

Comment: just call `observable(yourSavedJSON)`, no?

Comment: so if I have store as class, should I use this = observable(json) or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure extendObservable doesn't work.
I've used something like this in my code.

```
class MyStore {
  async load() {
      const cached = await browser.storage.local.get("cache");
      mobx.extendObservable(this, cached);
  }
}
```

***Edit***:

This seems to be not working, you need to access the properties after extendObservable in order to reload them, you could use autorun but just use another method.

I've implemented load function based on a simple forEach;
Try the following.

```
load = async () => {
    const { cache } = await JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cache"));

    Object.keys(cache).forEach(key => {
      this[key] = cache[key];
    });
  };
```

CodeSandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/late-snow-xppx0?ontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: `Error: [mobx] 'extendObservable' can only be used to introduce new properties. Use 'set' or 'decorate' instead`

Comment: Have you tried defining the data before loading? Like decorate(MyStore, { a: observable }. If you set the keys before the extendObservable It should work.

Comment: properties already defined in my class 
```export class AppStore {
  @observable activeTab: number = 0;
  @observable currentUser: string = "";```
and so one

Comment: I wrote a codesandbox showing a thing I used without extendObservables, I just did did a forEach loop over the cache and set the data.
Updated the answer as well.
https://codesandbox.io/s/late-snow-xppx0?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class, and "raw" json data, what i'm doing is to accept raw data in the constructor & then update the class properties.

For example, my raw data looks like this:

```
{
  users: [
    { id: 1, firstName: 'foo', lastName: 'bar', customer: { id: 1, name: 'bla' } },
    { id: 2, firstName: 'foo2', lastName: 'bar2', customer: { id: 2, name: 'customer' } },
  ];
}
```

```js
class User {
  id;
  @observable firstName;
  @observable lastName;
  customer;

  constructor(rawUser) {
    this.id = rawUser.id;
    this.firstName = rawUser.firstName;
    this.lastName = rawUser.lastName;
    this.customer = new Customer(rawUser.customer);
  }
}
```

```js
class UsersStore {
  @observable users = [];

  constructor(rawUsers) {
    this.users = rawUsers.map(rawUser => new User(rawUser));
  }
}
```

Then when I'm restoring the data I'm just using

```js
const usersStore = new UsersStore(rawData.users);
```

The **cool** thing in this approach is the **nesting handling**, each "level" handles its part.